# Magento 2.3.3 - Shipping Methods Issue

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.3.3

We are unable to get any Shipping Methods to show on customer check out.

Checking out as a guest (call to `estimate-shipping-method`) or as a registered user (call to `estimate-shipping-method-by-address-id`) are returning empty arrays.

[According to this..](https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/quoteGuestShipmentEstimationV1EstimateByExtendedAddressPost). I am missing the email and region_code as required in the payload.  On our live site the exact same payload is being delivered and working fine, missing those two attributes.  We are upgrading a stage site to Magento 2.3.3 and the customer wants to remove the one-page checkout and use the default Magento check out.

We have tried many of the fixes found through research and nothing seems to be helping at this time.  I am not sure what information you will need, so please feel free to ask and I will update with the information as soon as I am able.

Answer (score 0):

It has taken some time, but I believe we have found the issue.  For the sake of someone else out there who may have this situation, I will add the information.

It appears that the issue was with an Amasty extension, specifically Amasty_Shippingrestriction.  When we upgraded the development site, we lost all of our Shipping Restrictions.  Well, we retained all the names, but lost all of the conditions.  I am now working through replacing all the conditions from our live site to our stage site for further testing.  Please check to see if all of your Shipping Restriction conditions transferred if you are doing an upgrade and use the Amasty plug ins.

We were able to have shipping quotes appear once we disabled the Amasty_Shippingrestriction.